# Getting errors while installing yeoman on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, mendix

I am trying to install yeoman in windows with command: npm install -g yo

I am getting following errors:
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

npm WARN deprecated readdir-scoped-modules@1.1.0: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

changed 719 packages in 1m

80 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

I am trying to create a widget in mendix, so that it requires yeoman, but it is not installing.

when run the command 'npm ls -g yo', it showed me a path
I went to that path, there is yo file and yo commandscript.

but yo is recognised when try to generate the mendix widget.
Can someone help in this.

Comment: Those are warning, not errors. What do you get when you run `yo @mendix/widget widgetname`?

Comment: Also, did you follow this tutorial? https://docs.mendix.com/howto/extensibility/create-a-pluggable-widget-one/